# Allow Only Numbers and Letters Does NOT work in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript

How can I get this to work in Mozilla Firefox ?
It works just fine in IE and Chrome

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 

function isNumberLetter(evtNL)  {

            if ((evtNL.keyCode >= 48 && evtNL.keyCode <= 57) ||
               (evtNL.keyCode >= 65 && evtNL.keyCode <= 90) ||
               (evtNL.keyCode >= 97 && evtNL.keyCode <= 122))
                return true;

             return false;
        }//]]>  

</script>
```

Comment: Wild guess, by using `evtNL.which`

Comment: I assume this is called by some key event (e.g. keypress, keydown)?

Comment: use keyDown instead of keyPress and it should work just fine

Comment: you can maybe also try checking the opposite. ie : `!evtNL.keyCode < 48` etc... but that could get a bit annoying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you capture the keypress event, you can get the charCode:

```
$(document.body).on('keypress', function(event) {
    var isAlphaNum = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode).match(/[a-zA-Z0-9]/);
    if(isAlphaNum) {
        console.log('Letter or number');
    } else {
        console.log('Other key');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, it seems the third comment (by @dandavis) is correct.  I tried this in Firefox 30.0 (Aurora):

```
document.body.onkeypress = function (e) {
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    console.log(e.key);
}
```

which gives results like this:

```
0 
"a" 
0 
"b" 
0 
"c" 
0 
"d"
```

If I change `onkeypress` to `onkeydown` or `onkeyup` it works fine:

```
65 
"a" 
66 
"b" 
67 
"c" 
68 
"d"
```

EDIT:

It seems thet `e.which` also works with keypress, as suggested by @adeneo.

Answer (score 0):

After glancing at [Mozilla's developer network entry on keyboard events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent), it seemed you should use  `event.key` instead --assuming you're passing in an event.  keyCode appears to be deprecated.

*However*, event.key is not implemented yet. @dandavis points out that using `keyCode` should be cross-browser, anyway.

Comment: @dandavis from that article it almost seems as if there is no way to do this in mozilla

Comment: @metsales you would need to have a cross-browser solution.

Comment: keyCode has been good to me for years (just not for non-wordy chars on press events)...

Comment: there in lies the key issue... cross-browser... I'd be curious to know if there is a way to get numerical inputs cross browser without `key` as it has not been implemented yet.

Comment: yeah, it's called e.keyCode

Comment: then I'm a bit confused as to what you mean by non-wordy chars... like special characters?